# Unmarshal list of arbitrary struct and append it to slice with reflection

Tags: go, reflection

I would like to unmarshal a JSON string which will be a list of an arbitrary struct (determined at runtime), and append the unmarshalled list of structs to a slice supplied to the function (the type is unknown before runtime, but is a slice of the same time of the list being unmarshalled).

Here is a minimal example of what I'm trying to achieve ([playground link here](https://play.golang.org/p/H8IRDXLhNqt)):

```
type Foo struct {
    Name string
}

func get(results interface{}) (interface{}, error) {
    resVal := reflect.ValueOf(results)
    data := reflect.New(resVal.Type())

    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(`[{"name":"data"},{"name":"test"}]`), data.Interface())
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return reflect.Append(resVal, data).Interface(), nil
}

func main() {
    results := []Foo{}
    newResults, err := get(results)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", newResults)
}
```

I believe the above should work, but I'm getting:

```
panic: reflect.Set: value of type *[]main.Foo is not assignable to type main.Foo
```

Comment: I could not figure out why you did not use a slice of empty interface.

Comment: I mean you really did write this https://play.golang.org/p/VtB3xOdr9iY

Comment: @mh-cbon unfortunately your example wouldn't work if I have to call `get()` multiple times and append to the same `results` (instead of overwriting). Is that correct?

Comment: there is many ways to work around this. this is a complicated option https://play.golang.org/p/EMoWZ1aFfMX  this is simpler and more readable https://play.golang.org/p/HNeFK75AGRx

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`AppendSlice`](https://golang.google.cn/pkg/reflect/#AppendSlice) to append the individual elements of a slice represented by a `reflect.Value`. Note that your `data` represents a pointer to a slice, so you have to do `data.Elem()` to get to the slice.

```golang
reflect.AppendSlice(resVal, data.Elem()).Interface()
```

https://play.golang.org/p/xTfoEvgMoh_U

---

Or you can use [`Append`](https://golang.google.cn/pkg/reflect/#Append) but then you'll have to unpack the slice represented by `data.Elem()` manually.

```golang
data = data.Elem()
slice := make([]reflect.Value, data.Len())
for i := range slice {
    slice[i] = data.Index(i)
}
reflect.Append(resVal, slice...).Interface()
```

https://play.golang.org/p/YcDvv24xZoo